# vertical text in flexbox layout

Tags: css, text, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a front page layout for my portfolio that Im trying to implement some vertical text on. The right section (blue) is where my name will be written vertically. When I try to rotate the text via css transform, it screws up the layout when scrolling. So Im stumped. Youll have to increase the size to full page to view the layout correctly. Name should extend full length of the blue container. 
https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/BdrdZJ

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
<div class="svg-container">
  <div class="svg-logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
  <p>WHO AM I?</p>
  <p>WHAT DO I DO?</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="middle">
<div class="top">
  <nav>
    <a>Link1</a>
    <a>Link2</a>
    <a>Link3</a>
    <a>Link4</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Im an extremely</br> passionate User</br> Interface Design</br> + 
Developer</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
<h1></h1>
</div>
</div>



.container{
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
background: black;
}



.left{
display: flex;
flex: 1;
background: gray;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}
.svg-container{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
background: yellow;
width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 }
.svg-logo{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background: orange;
}
.question-container{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
background: green;
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
}
p{
display: flex;
margin-right: 10px;
}



.middle{
display: flex;
flex: 3;
background: red;
flex-direction: column;
}
.top{
display: flex;
flex: 1;
background: aqua;
}
nav{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 65px 0 0 65px;
}

a:before {
content: '\2014';
position: absolute;
margin-left: -40px;
} 
a{
margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
font-size: 24px;
}


.bottom{
display: inline-flex;
flex: 1;
background: brown;
align-items: flex-start;
}
h1{
 margin-left: 25px;
font-size: 55px;
}


.right{
display: flex;
flex: .5;
background: blue;
}

.name{
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: OK i now have the text rotated, but now it is taking up two lines. I would like it to be stretched the size of the blue container. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sideways-lr` alone (without `transform`) will solve it, though as of today only Firefox support it.

Use [`writing-mode: vertical-lr;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) in combination with `transform: rotate` and it will behave more as you expect

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZMMeP)

Stack snippet

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}



.left{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: gray;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.svg-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.svg-logo{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
.question-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
p{
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}



.middle{
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  background: red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: aqua;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 65px 0 0 65px;
}

a:before {
  content: '\2014';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
a{
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}


.bottom{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: brown;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
h1{
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 55px;
}


.right{
  display: flex;
  flex: .2;
  background: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.name{
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);            /*  changed  */
  background: pink;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;                   /*  for IE  */
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;             /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <div class="svg-logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="question-container">
      <p>WHO AM I?</p>
      <p>WHAT DO I DO?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="top">
      <nav>
        <a>Link1</a>
        <a>Link2</a>
        <a>Link3</a>
        <a>Link4</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h1>Im an extremely</br> passionate User</br> Interface Design</br> + Developer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2 class="name">Travis Martin</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it however when I try to capitalize the name/increase the font (to take up more of the blue container), it increases the size of the blue container. Is there any way to capitalize the text and increase its font without increasing the size of the blue container?

Comment: @TravisMartin Add `min-width: 0;` to the `.right` ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLjbGN

Comment: i did that however i think whats happening is the middle container is being pushed smaller as I increase the size of the font. This wont work because I need the text to take up close to all of the available space in that right side container.

Comment: @TravisMartin Well, it doesn't do that for me. If you find this useful, upvote, if not, let me know and I delete my answer

Comment: I came close, however my workaround was to get rid of the right container altogether and put the text in the empty space left from the right and middle containers. However when I implement this layout, I will have a background image so will show up in the middle section, but should have semitransparent right and left sections. I can't accomplish this if the name text isn't actually in a container. Therefore I will be unable to put a semi transparent layer behind the name text. The blue color is what will eventually be the background image (middle gray section will also be background image)

Comment: @TravisMartin Sounds like you made use of my suggestions, and since the 2 keys here is `min-width: 0;` and `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`, I think an upvote/accept would be reasonable. What do you think?